# How to handle overflow (add color) or underflow (subtract color)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to write an application that can extract images from a cinefilm (e.g. Super8 or Normal8) in order to generate a video from the extracted images. I am trying to do that in WPF using .NET 5.0 and C#.
Some of the images need color corrections  ( brighter, darker, sharper, etc );

.NET 5.0 provides a structure  System.Windows.Media.Color which provides the methods **Add(Color1,Color2)** and **Subtract(Color1, Color2)**.
If you perform this methods in a C# program it might happen, that you get color channel results that should have argb values below 0 or above 255.

I expect a value of 0 (zero) for negative results and a value of 255 for results above 255.

--- sample -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    //
    // the correction color is defined as a static System.Windows.Media.Color
    // e.g.like Color.FromArgb(255, 20, 15, 10);
    //   
    public Color CorrectARGBValues(byte a, byte red, byte green, byte blue)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Color aOldColor = Color.FromArgb(a, red, green, blue);
        System.Windows.Media.Color aNewColor = Color.Add(aOldColor, aCorrectionColor);
        return aNewColor;
    }
```

---

The mentioned functions seem not to handle this exceptions - e. g. by inserting 0 for a negative value or inserting 255 for a value above 255.
Can anybody recommend a simple solution to this problem.
I cannot find anything appropriate to this simple problem in the MS Documentation nor in the Internet.
A solution may be to handle each color pixel in a WhriteableBitmap separately, but that seems to be extremely awkward.
Regards
Wolfgang

Comment: I am not an expert, but it's unclear: what exactly do you expect for whiter than white or blacker than black?

Comment: Have a look at the implementation of the Add method. As the Color struct is implemented using 4 bytes, on for each channel, you will not be able to get values outside of the range of 0 - 255.
https://source.dot.net/#PresentationCore/System/Windows/Media/Color.cs,7244816b6f563fc2